# Live PDF Preview with AJAX and jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, pdf

I am trying to create a live PDF preview using two main components:

- jQuery on the front-end
- A server-side library that returns PDF binary data

My client-side code sends POSTS to the PDF-generator that fills out the form and shoots back binary, which I can subsequently show in a new browser tab with some simple headers.  Simple enough.

I took the next step and tried to use an AJAX request to load the updated PDF anytime a form field is filled out, and while the request and response work, I don't know how to render the response on the same page.  I'm stuck with a bunch of garbled PDF binary data.

Do I need to create an iFrame on the page?  Can I embed the resulting PDF data into a `<div>` tag?

Answer (score 1):

You will likely need to based encode the PDF and insert in object tag using datauri. Note that it will not work except in Chrome and Firefox and not on mobile.

We do this on http://www.cloudformatter.com/css2pdf in the embed option in the formatting menu.